# Using spool in shell script but does not output file

Tags: shell, sqlplus

I have a stored procedure in SQL written and I am trying to write the info from that procedure to an output file using shell script. I use spool, but I do not see the output file after the script was run.

My script:

```
run_procedure(){
userId="abc"
psswd="abcd"
package="Retrieve_data" 
procedure="RETRIEVE_SERVER_DATA"
echo ${package}.${procedure}
sqlplus ${userId}/${passwd} >dev/null 2>&1 <<EOF
set serveroutput on;
set line 7000;
set feedback off;
set termout off;
spool /tmp/test.txt;
EXECUTE ${package}.${procedure};
spool off;
exit;
EOF
)
```

Here is where I call the above function:

```
if [[ $RETURN -eq 0 ]]; then
run_procedure
fi
```

(My return is equal to 0, by the way.)

Comment: your last `)`, shouldn't be `}` ?

Comment: yes, i have it in my code as '}'. my mistake here